# assigning the number of clicks to a hidden value

Tags: javascript, php

```
 <form action='productsphp.php' method='post'>

      <button type="button" onclick="add1()">Add</button>

      <input type="hidden" id="p1" value="" name="p1"/>        
       <input type="submit" value="Save" />
 </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function add1(){
    var p= document.getElemenetById('p1').value;
   var p1=0;
  p1=p+1;
   p=p1;

}

   </script>
```

In the productsphp.php page

```
      <?php

    if(isset($_POST['p1'])){
        $p1=$_POST['p1'];
        echo "p1 is".$p1;
        }
    ?>
```

It is not working.
I want everytime the button is clicked to go the add1() function and increment it.So I can know how many clicks the user has clicked.Then when pressing save to save the number of clicks in the hidden value and then take the value and save it in the database.But the value is still nothing.please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function name has a typo (`getElemenetById`, extra `e`) and you never resend the value to the input field. Try:

```
<form action='productsphp.php' method='post'>
    <button type="button" onclick="add1()">Add</button>
    <input type="hidden" id="p1" value="" name="p1"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function add1(){
    var p= !parseInt(document.getElementById('p1').value) ? 0 : parseInt(document.getElementById('p1').value);
    p++;
    document.getElementById('p1').value = p;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Great, please accept this answer if it resolves your issue.

Comment: @AssoumZoghbi something happened to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function add1(){
    var p = document.getElementById('p1').value,
        p1 = parseInt(p) + 1;
    document.getElementById('p1').value = p1;
}
```

This way, you use the value of `p1` after calculating it.
You should also need to set the initial value of `p1`:

```
<input type="hidden" id="p1" value="0" name="p1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use another element at all, you could manipulate an attribute on your current element like data-clicks. It would look like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="add1(this);" data-clicks="0">Add</button>
```

And the function will be:

```
 function add1(element){
      var currentClicks = element.getAttribute('data-clicks');
      element.setAttribute('data-clicks', currentClicks + 1);
 }
```

Reducing the DOM elements on your page improves performance, consider that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action='productsphp.php' method='post'>

      <button type="button" onclick="add1()">Add</button>

      <input type="text" id="p1" value="" name="p1"/>        
       <input type="submit" value="Save" />
 </form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function add1(){
    var p= document.getElementById('p1');
    if(p.value) { 
        p.value = parseInt(p.value) +1;
    }else {
        p.value = 1;
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 1-liner :D

```
function add1(){
    document.getElementById("p1").value = Number(document.getElementById("p1").value) + 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note: Your clicks count could be cheated easily with this way. use ajax with jquery instead**

You could use simple javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i=document.getElementById('p1').value;
i=(isNaN(i))?0:i;
function add1(){
   count++;
   //alert(count);
   document.getElementById('p1').value=count;
}
</script>
```

Or Jquery

```
<script>
var i=$('#p1').val();
i=(isNaN(i))?0:i;
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#p1').val(++i);
});
</script>
```

Here is complete html file

```
 <html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action='productsphp.php' method='post'>

      <button type="button" onclick="add1()">Add</button>

      <input type="hidden" id="p1" value="" name="p1"/>        
       <input type="submit" value="Save" />
 </form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
//use one at a time. This is just a demonstration how to do this in both 
//jquery and javascript

/* Javascript way of doing this - 
var i=document.getElementById('p1').value;
i=(isNaN(i))?0:i;
function add1(){
   i++;
   document.getElementById('p1').value=i;
}
*/
/* JQuery way of doing this*/
var i=$('#p1').val();
i=(isNaN(i))?0:i;
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#p1').val(++i);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You must not have given it an initial value. `<input type="hidden" id="p1" value="20" name="p1"/>`

Comment: no dear :/ checked again,..it works.. tested it with this <input type="hidden" id="p1" value="testing" name="p1"/>